# Transform every two array items into associative array pairs

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative-array

I'm trying to make an associative array from my string, but nothing works and I don't know where the problem is.

My string looks like:

```
$string = "somethink;452;otherthink;4554;somethinkelse;4514"
```

I would like to make an associative array, where "text" is the key, and the number is value.

```
Somethink => 452 otherthink => 4554 Somethinkelse => 4514
```

I tried to convert the string into an array and then to the associative array but it's not working. I decided to use:

```
$array=explode(";",$string);
```

Then tried to use a `foreach` loop but it's not working. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex and `array_combine`:

```
$string = "somethink;452;otherthink;4554;somethinkelse;4514";

preg_match_all("'([A-Za-z]+);(\d+)'", $string, $matches);
$assoc = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($assoc);
```

Using a traditional for loop:

```
$string = "somethink;452;otherthink;4554;somethinkelse;4514";
$arr = explode(";", $string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i += 2) {
    $assoc[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}

print_r($assoc);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [somethink] => 452
    [otherthink] => 4554
    [somethinkelse] => 4514
)
```

Note that there must be an even number of pairs; you can add a condition to test this and use a substitute value for any missing keys, or omit them.